# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Whatsapp

Tags: url, syntax-error, schema, whatsapp

I'm using an app to send text on whatsapp, I tried with the next code, the code is correct and work well in web, but when I used on `aessegurosyfianzas` it did not work. So I tried with a plugin whatsapp chat live but neither.

the code is:

```
<div style=" width: 170px; margin: 5px; padding: 2px; background-color; #189d0e; border-radius: 15px; color: white; ">
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5214771478702&text=Hola &#333;que tal&#63; este es un texto predeterminado de prueba" target="_blank">
    Chatea con nosotros
  </a>
</div>
```

so the put:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity( intent );
    return true;
  }
});
```

but it still isn't working.